# AWS Linking Dynamo DB and S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm creating a project that tracks potential employees for a company.

I want to upload some pdfs to an AWS S3 bucket. I want to store a link to each pdf inside an existing dynamoDB table (one record per pdf). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I am dynamically generating new users and want to be able to add the pdf to the bucket and the link in dynamoDB simultaneously. Can I do this via a lambda function at the same time?

Comment: Where are the PDF files that you want the Lambda function to upload to S3?

Comment: The pdf would be on a person's local computer.

Comment: How does the PDF get to your app? Are you writing a serverless (Lambda-based) webapp that the user uploads a PDF to, or something else? Clearly you can store a PDF to S3 *and* write to DynamoDB from the same code, so it's not clear to me what your challenge actually is.

Comment: I have never done it so it isn't obvious to me. My web app is serverless. First time setting up a serverless backend.

Comment: I would take a look at https://serverless-stack.com/ and https://aws-amplify.github.io/.

Comment: @PDB did you see my answer, my code?

Comment: @ene_salinas yes thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Can I do this via a lambda function at the same time?* .-

yes, you can do. you must have the following things in mind:

- Create lambda
- Configure IAM role for execute lambda
- Add trigger and its permissions, example for dynamodb:

  ```
  Allow: dynamodb:PutItem
  ```

  [image]
- Add trigger and its permissions for bucket s3:

  ```
  Allow: s3:PutObject
  ```

  [image]

Also, with [serverless](https://serverless.com) is very easy, only you must configure yml config and associate the resources (in this case s3), [here](https://github.com/ns4lin4s/stackoverflow/tree/master/53109644) an example that i did.

If you want to see it working:

```
npm install
npm run deploy
```

If you want to test:

```
npm install
npm run test
```

*important: you must configured AWS Credentials in your machine, [here's the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html)*